# How to use orderby in mongodb if there are possible null values?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have multiple documents with this structure in my MongoDB:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56792b6898015712282264d5"), 
    "Stamp" : ISODate("2015-12-22T10:52:24.640+0000"), 
    "Key" : null, 
    "RoleTitle" : "SDE", 
    "StartDate" : ISODate("2014-08-01T07:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "EndDate" : null, 
    "Salary" : null, 
    "PayType" : null, 
    "Currency" : null
}
```

In case of a current Job, the End Date field is set to `null`

I want to **find the Recent Job from the db** and this is how I am doing it currently in C# and it is **throwing Null Pointer Exception** because collection contains documents with EndDate as `null`:

```
var filter = Builders<WorkHistory>.Filter.Where(u => u.MemberOid == oid);
var doc = db.GetFilteredDocuments(filter).OrderByDescending(u => u.EndDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

I also want to sort these documents by StartDate in case EndDate is `null`.
How do I find the recent job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those API methods which allow you to pass a closure should better be avoided (not sure if it gets somehow translated to Javascript and executed on the database or if the filter is executed on the client-side after requesting the whole collection content, but both alternatives are terrifying). In your case, the operations you implement as C# functions are very trivial and covered by the standard API which directly translates to native MongoDB functionality:

Instead of `Filter.Where(function)` use [`Filter.Eq("field", value)`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_Eq__1.htm)

Instead of `.OrderByDescending(function)` use `.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("field"))`.

Should you ever encounter one of the rare edge-cases which can not be covered with the native MongoDB functionality and absolutely must use a function, write your functions in a way that they handle null values. This, for example, would treat each field with a date of `null` as being January 1, year 1 A.D. at 00:00:00.000:

```
OrderByDescending(u => u.EndDate == null ? new DateTime(0) : u.EndDate)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I will try it out. But I have changed the query to make 2 queries now, one with getfiltereddocuments where end date is null and sort by startdate and in case when there are no null values in enddate, directly sort using enddate